# LNK 2001 when using freetype

Tags: c++, lib, freetype2

I am trying to include freetype library into my project.

I downloaded the binaries from https://github.com/ubawurinna/freetype-windows-binaries

When I'm trying to compile, I get
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct FT_LibraryRec_ * ftlib" (?ftlib@@3PEAUFT_LibraryRec_@@EA)`

And other LNK2001 like that.

I looked for an answer and I found, that I need to link `msvcmrt.lib` and `msvcrt.lib`
It didn't work as well.

I am linking the lib file with linker and adding the additional include directory. What might be wrong?

The include lines in file:

```cpp
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

EDIT: linker command:
`lib\freetype\win64\freetype.lib;opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;lib\glfw-3.3.2\lib-vc2019\glfw3.lib;lib\glew-2.2.0\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib;lib\soil\libs\soil.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Comment: Perhaps you are mixing up 32 bit and 64 bit? If you try to link with the wrong library it gets ignored.

Comment: I think I am linking the good one, but I will try 32bit

Comment: @john Doesn't work

Comment: It's hard to help since you haven't really explained what you are doing. You must be making some mistake somewhere. You haven't mentioned adding an additional library directory (only an additional include directory), did you do that?

Comment: Add your link line to the question (you can increase the build output verbosity to make it appear in your build outputs).

Comment: Echo what Mansoor said, the full linker command line also appears under linker properties. It would be helpful to see that.

Comment: Your glew library is 64 bit so hopefully you used the 64 bit version of freetype and you are building a 64 bit application

Comment: ***I looked for an answer and I found, that I need to link msvcmrt.lib and msvcrt.lib It didn't work as well.*** No that is not the solution to this problem. I believe this is bad advice for solving most issues I can think of. If you have a problem with the CRT you likely need to match the CRT library between your application and dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be something else, not connected in any way to linking freetype. For some reason, when I'm trying to create global variable using non-default type (GLuint, FT_Library etc.) I get strange error. This has happened once before, but I still don't know what exactly is the problem. Anyway, the solution is to not use

```cpp
extern FT_Library ftlib;
```

In header file.

Comment: It is fine to use it in a .h file.  But you'll need a .cpp file to define the variable, you just forgot to do so.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I define this variable? I mean: what value should I set? `*new FT_Library()`?